# python decorator doesn't work

Tags: python, decorator

I am new to python. I want to pass the arguments to a class derorator:

```
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(TestClass, self).__init__()
        self.name = name

    def age(self, func, age=0):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if age >= 18:
                print "you are not a child"
            else:
                print "you are a child"
            func()
        return wrapper

test = TestClass("liu")

@test.age(age=12)
def hello():
    print "hello, world!"
```

but the error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/liux/Desktop/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    @test.age(age=12)
TypeError: age() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

Any idea for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`age` should be a method that returns a decorator. (not a decorator)

So it should looks like this:

```
def age(self, age=0):
    def deco(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if age >= 18:
                print "you are not a child"
            else:
                print "you are a child"
            func()  # OR  return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return deco
```